# cannot submit a form with jQuery

Tags: forms, jquery, form-submit

I've this form

```
<form id="frm_main" action="#" method=POST>
 <input type=hidden name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
 <input id='file' name="file" type="file">
 &nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type=submit id='btn_import' name='btn_import' value='Importar' />
 <input type=hidden id="uploadResponseType" name="mimetype" value="html" />
 <input type=hidden id="func" name="func" value="upload" />
 <div id="uploadOutput"></div>
 </form>
```

So, the problem became when I try to post the upleaded file. If I use ajaxSubmit function the form is submited but it doesn't return to the page; and if I use $.ajax function, it doesn't sent the uploeade file. The thing is that I need to return to the same page because I've to do some stuff with the file content. I've already tried lot of combinations but I'm still having the same results. The code to handle submit look like this

```
$( '#frm_main' ).bind( 'submit', function( e ) {
// e.preventDefault(); // <-- important
$( this ).ajaxSubmit({
target: '#uploadOutput', // <-- div container
type: "POST", // <-- override, just in case.
url: "/process.php", // <-- server-side handler
data: "func=upload", // <-- parameter for post purpouse
beforeSubmit: function(a,f,o) {
o.dataType = $('#uploadResponseType').val();    // should be 'html'.
$('#uploadOutput').html('Submitting...');
},
success: function(data) {
var $out = $('#uploadOutput');
$out.html('Form success handler received: <strong>' + typeof data + '</strong>');
$out.append('<div><pre>'+ data +'</pre></div>');
}
});
return false;
});
```

And I've already tried with next code

```
$('#frm_main').bind('submit', function() {
var formdata = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
    url:    '/process.php',
    data:   formdata,
    dataType: 'html', 
    success: function(data){
        var $out = $('#uploadOutput');
        $out.html('Form success handler received: <strong>' + typeof data + '</strong>');
    }
});
return false;
});
```

And process.php code looks like this

```
switch($_POST['func']) {
  case 'upload' : 
    $output = upload_file ();
    echo $output;
   break;
 default : 
   echo "<BR/>INVALID";
   break;
}
?>
```

Can somebody help me with this situation, please? Any help will be gratefully appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need form enctype="multipart/form-data" to upload files?

Comment: Yes, I certainly do need an "enctype" parameter in the form but that is not the problem ... I had to solve this situation with some kind of trick, by catching the click event at the submit button and then calling ajaxSumbit inside the handler of that button. Didn't found any ohter way :(
Thank you for your answer ... It was helpfull indeed ;)